# How to display custom text as a label in an excel cell for a particular column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-template

I want to create a custom template for users with data validations. I have completed the data validation part but I want to display all the cell values in a certain columns as dropdown values with a label like "Select from dropdown".

[image: Screenshot for sample view]

Comment: Are you asking about changing `--Select Values--` to read `Select from dropdown`?  If so, that is within your data validation itself.  I cannot see how you are pulling the information, so I am unsure if that is updating the exact line entry in the data validation or updating a table on another sheet which the data validation references.

Comment: no for sample..I have just copy pasted the values there.. I want it to display when the value goes back to blank and also apply it to all the cell values under the column.

Comment: Then you need VBA Programming

Answer (score 0):

Once you applied the List, you can add the Text "Select from dropdown" by copy and paste (as value) to the list cells.
Then you have it as you want, but once you choose a value from the drop down and delete it again, then the cell will remain empty. The text "Select from dropdown" will not display anymore. Solving this, you will need to use VBA programming.

[image]